# GHUnit access private variable

Tags: objective-c, tdd, private-members, gh-unit

I'm trying to access a private class variable in my unit test:

```
Class
 - private variable abc;

unit test
category/extension above the unittest m file content
 @property (...) variable abc;
```

but within the test, I always get a unrecognized selector error...
Is there any trick making private variables visible/testable?

Sorry, found nothing using google ;)

Greetings,
matthias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `[obj valueForKey:@"_ivar"]`

you can also make a category to that class and you can access any private variables during the method

```
@implementation MyClass (UnitTestAddition)

- (id)getPrivateVariable {
    return _ivar;
}

@end
```

Comment: excelent, obj valueforkey is working - do you know why obj._ivar does not? Thanks!!!

Comment: to do or obj.ivar, the class must implemented `[ivar]` either in the implementation or synthesized by the compiler. otherwise it will be unrecognized selector exception. however, you can implement the accessor in the category